# Function for replacing subsequences

Tags: list, vector, replace, clojure, sequence

Is there a function that could replace subsequences? For example:

```
user> (good-fnc [1 2 3 4 5] [1 2] [3 4 5])
;; => [3 4 5 3 4 5]
```

I know that there is `clojure.string/replace` for strings:

```
user> (clojure.string/replace "fat cat caught a rat" "a" "AA")
;; => "fAAt cAAt cAAught AA rAAt"
```

Is there something similar for vectors and lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that plays nicely with lazy seq inputs. Note that it can take an infinite lazy sequence `(range)` without looping infinitely as a loop based version would.

```
(defn sq-replace
  [match replacement sq]
  (let [matching (count match)]
    ((fn replace-in-sequence [[elt & elts :as sq]]
       (lazy-seq
        (cond (empty? sq)
              ()
              (= match (take matching sq))
              (concat replacement (replace-in-sequence (drop matching sq)))
              :default
              (cons elt (replace-in-sequence elts)))))
     sq)))

#'user/sq-replace
user> (take 10 (sq-replace [3 4 5] ["hello, world"] (range)))
(0 1 2 "hello, world" 6 7 8 9 10 11)
```

I took the liberty of making the sequence argument the final argument, since this is the convention in Clojure for functions that walk a sequence.

Comment: I tested my solution (which turned out to be this one in disguise) with `(apply str (sq-replace "a" "AA" "fat cat caught a rat"))"`, getting `"fat cat caught a rat"`! What's wrong? Hint: `(apply str (sq-replace (seq "a") "AA" "fat cat caught a rat"))` produces `"fAAt cAAt cAAught AA rAAt"`. A (rare?) case where a type-checker would help.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
(defn good-fnc [s sub r]
  (loop [acc []
         s s]
    (cond
      (empty? s) (seq acc)
      (= (take (count sub) s) sub) (recur (apply conj acc r)
                                          (drop (count sub) s))
      :else (recur (conj acc (first s)) (rest s)))))
```

Comment: Yes it does, however I'm interested in standard function (I think this is quite basic operation, so if there is something for strings, there should be something for vectors and lists...)

Comment: The Clojure string operations are mostly just jvm interop. Many operations on strings are not supported on general sequences.

Comment: @noisesmith, So it means that there is no standard function for this?

Comment: @Mark, what language has a standard function for this?

Comment: @ponzao, I know no language that has standard function for this, nevertheless, every time I learn some language and do some practical stuff, I need this function, so unless I'm completely unique, there must be a library for this sort of operations on sequences.

Comment: @Mark - I wouldn't be surprised if something like this existed in [flatland/useful](https://clojars.org/org.flatland/useful) - but I know of nothing built in

Answer (score 1):

My previous (now deleted) answer was incorrect because this was not as trivial as I first thought, here is my second attempt:

```
(defn seq-replace
  [coll sub rep]
  (letfn [(seq-replace' [coll]
            (when-let [s (seq coll)]
              (let [start (take (count sub) s)
                    end (drop (count sub) s)]
                (if (= start sub)
                  (lazy-cat rep (seq-replace' end))
                  (cons (first s) (lazy-seq (seq-replace' (rest s))))))))]
    (seq-replace' coll)))
```